# quadratic sum of Bernoulli numbers

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, bernoulli-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

Is it possible to express
$$ A_n = (2n-3)! \sum_{i=0}^{2n} \frac{B_i B_{2n-i}}{i! (2n-i)!} (2^{1-i} -1) (2^{1-2n+i} -1)(2^i -1) $$
in a more compact form,
perhaps using the identity
$$ E_{2n} = 2^{2n+1} \binom{2n}{2}^{-1} \sum_{i=0}^{2n} B_i B_{2n-i} \binom{2n}{i} (2^{2n-i} -1) (2^{1-i} -1) $$
or a similar one, where B are Bernoulli numbers and E Euler numbers?

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{E_k}{k!} x^k = \frac{1}{\cosh x} $$

Comment: Looks like a kind of convolution, so you may be able get a generating function.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$ \sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{B_i}{i!}x^i=\frac{x}{e^x-1},\qquad \sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{B_i}{i}x^i 2^{i-1} = \frac{x}{e^{2x}-1} \tag{1}$$
hence 
$$\sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{B_i}{i!}(2-2^{i})x^i = \frac{x}{\sinh x},\qquad \sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{B_i}{i!}(2^{1-i}-1)x^i=\frac{x/2}{\sinh(x/2)}\tag{2}$$
and
$$ \frac{A(n)}{(2n-3)!}=[x^{2n}]\left(\frac{x^2/2}{\sinh(x)\sinh(x/2)}-\frac{x^2/4}{\sinh^2(x/2)} \right)=[x^{2n}]\left(-\frac{x^2}{8\cosh^2\frac{x}{4}\cosh\frac{x}{2}}\right)\tag{3}$$

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer; is it possible to also get an expression involving only $B_{2n}$ and $E_{2n}$ or similar?

Comment: @jj_p: you may answer such question by yourself, given the RHS of $(3)$. What are the generating functions of $B_n$ and $E_n$? Can $(3)$ be expressed as a linear combination of them?

Comment: Actually I missed a numerical factor in front of A

Comment: @jj_p: that does not change much.

Comment: I wanted to show that $A_n = \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}n(n-1)}((2^{2n}-1)B_{2n}-nE_{2n-2})$, but I'm not able to play with the generating functions.